# is $\:\: x \not\in S \:\:$ same as $\:\:\neg (x \in S)\:\:$ same as $\:\:x \in {S}^\mathsf{c}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the following list, $S$ is any set and ${S}^\mathsf{c}$ is its complement:

1. $\:\: x \not\in S $
2. $\:\: \neg (x \in S)\:\:$
3. $\:\: x \in {S}^\mathsf{c}$

I am sure that 1 and 2 are equivalent but I have been pondering if 3 is also equivalent to the previous two. I have yet to come across a book that gives me a proof or disproof or say something about it. I cannot offer a attempt to prove it because I have no idea how to tackle it.

Comment: What is the definition of $S^c$?

Comment: By definition, $S^c=\{x \in U:x \notin S\}$, where $U$ is the universal set.

Comment: @SeanXie what is the "universal set"?

Comment: @UmbertoP. The way I've learnt it, the "universal set" is more formally known as the "[universe of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse)".

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. There is some confusion over the complement notation, but that's really what's at the core of the user's problem. I think that this question can be useful for other users in the future who are confused about the subtle difference between $x \notin S$ and $x \in S^c$. And the difference really is nontrivial yet subtle: one presumes the existence of an ambient set, while the other does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd give a slightly more elaborate answer, in light of the discussion regarding the complement notation in the comments.

Strictly speaking, you can only take the complement of a set with respect to another set. If you have a set $X$ and a subset $S \subseteq X$, then the complement of $S$ in $X$, often denoted $X \backslash S$, is defined to be:
$$ X \backslash S = \{ x \in X : x \notin S \}. $$
When you use the notation $S^c$, there is an implicit assumption that all our elements and subsets are contained in some "ambient set" $X$. In this case, the notation $S^c$ means the same thing as $X \backslash S$. Then, when you write "$x \in S^c$", what you mean is $x \in X$ and $x \in X \backslash S$. Equivalently, $x \in X$ and $x \notin S$.

So, regarding your three equivalent statements, the confusion may be cleared up once we ask: what is $x$? If $x$ could be anything, then the notation $S^c$ is not well-defined. However, if we are considering $x$ to be an element of some ambient space $X$, then the notation $S^c$ means $X \backslash S$, and we get the equivalence you are after. I've restated a more explicit version below.

> Let $X$ be any set, let $S \subseteq X$, and let $S^c$ be the complement of $S$ (in $X$). If $x \in X$, then the following are equivalent.
>
> 1. $x \notin S$
> 2. $\neg (x \in S)$
> 3. $x \in S^c$
>
> You've convinced yourself that 1. is equivalent to 2. To see that 1. is equivalent to 3., just note that $S^c = X \backslash S = \{ x \in X : x \notin S\}$ by definition. Since $x \in X$, $x \in S^c$ is equivalent to $x \notin S$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, those conditions are equivalent.  $S^c$ means the complement of $S$.

Comment: Let $\mathbf R$ denote the set of real numbers. What is $\mathbf R^c$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. With no other context, it is reasonable to assume that the "ambient space" is $\mathbb{R}$ itself. In this case, $\mathbb{R}^c = \varnothing$.

Comment: @Sambo very good. Now let $S$ be a set. What is $S^c$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Your question seems disingenuous to me. The notation $S^c$ is only used when there is an understood "ambient space" $X$ such that $S \subseteq X$. The notation is of course ambiguous or undefined otherwise.